# Change in the repository using SVN Relocate

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using my old SVN repository (svn://192.168.1.56/Accessories) and i have created a new repository (svn://192.168.1.56/Accessories_1) for making some additional changes. I have committed all latest changes to my newly created SVN. Now i want to commit the latest changes to the old svn too because that is the main repository we are maintaining. I have made a try to use svn-> switch but it doesn't work and also i want to maintain the revision numbers on the old SVN.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this with client tools. you should use

`svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`